# Where is this missing part to the "Tron: Legacy" soundtrack?

Tags: music, tron-legacy

I finally bought the *Tron: Legacy* original soundtrack. I have listened to the soundtrack a lot since then and realized something: 
Where is the part of the song from the scene above the Sea of Simulation, where Rinzler/Tron flies upside-down above the Jet of Flynn (x2) and Quorra? In the scene Kevin says "Tron?" and during this, the sound goes a bit dull with fast highs, but smooth synthesizer sounds, just for a few seconds. Is there another album, where this part is available?

The song similar to the rest of the scene sounds like the Song *C.L.U.*.

Please watch the scene, I am NOT looking for the Song "Sea of Simulation", it is JUST the location where the scene takes part.

Comment: It's entirely possible that it IS one of the songs from the soundtrack but mixed slightly differently or even edited when it was mixed into the final film. This is a pretty common process.

Comment: It simplay isn't, because the base is still the Song *C.L.U.*

Comment: Not sure, but I know that players of the ARG were given access to a number of tracks. Maybe an exclusive one just for us?

Comment: It's normal practice for composers to record 'inserts' that can be inserted into a scene (usually because the scene was edited to be longer or something). These short pieces of music are inserted into the scene in the film-version, but they are rarely featured in the soundtrack, probably because you'd be able to tell they weren't part of the original recording, making for a jarring listening experience. Also, at the risk of stating the obvious, they almost never release the full score (which would be about 2 hours of music); they just release the best 40-75 minutes in the soundtrack album(s).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Walt Disney Records released a single disc version (22 tracks) inside the US, a double disc version outside the US (27 total tracks), with iTunes and Amazon MP3 versions having 24 and 23 tracks, respectively.  If purchased from Nokia Ovi, you also get 23 tracks, but a different bonus track than Amazon.  The Other Wiki also mentions "Vinyl edition bonus tracks", bringing the total to 29.

At last count, there has been released 30 individual tracks, but not all of them are available from any single source.  [There has been some controversy over this decision.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron:_Legacy_(soundtrack))

[See Howard Taylor's discussion of the OST.](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/blog/tron-legacy-soundtrack)

EDIT:

I re-watched the scene in question (Chapter 17: Air Battle on my DVD).  The music in the scene (which takes place OVER the Sea of Simulation) was later compiled into Track 18:C.L.U. of the single CD.  From 1:46:50 to 1:47:05, the style of the music does change.  Flynn is heard saying "TRON, what have they done to you?".

I have acquired the additional 8 tracks given in my answer above.  While the Amazon MP3 Track (also titled) "Sea of Simulation" is done in a similar arpeggio style, it is NOT the 15 second clip in question.  I believe that Disney/Daft Punk has simply not released these 15 seconds.

Comment: Also note that "Sea of Simulation" mentioned in the OP is from Amazon MP3.

Comment: is there also the Part I mentioned?

Comment: I only own the single disc CD (22 tracks).  I'm not sure if any of the other tracks contain the piece you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but then I think you didn't understand my question. The question was not if there are other albums and how much or the track "Sea of Simulation". The Sea was just mentioned as location where the scene take part. I asked if the part is anywhere on a soundtrack :(

Comment: @souichiro That's probably also the name of it.  Happens a lot in soundtracks, especially when it's an instrumental (when there's no words)

Comment: This didn't address the question, or the track.

Comment: @Izkata it is not. And I didn't asked for the Song "Sea of Simulation", the reference was just to the place. Watch the scene again and maybe finally, someone can answer my question..

Comment: THANK YOU :) So I will now directly ask Daft Punk about it! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're talking about

I wondered the same, and the only place I found it after quite a search is

Which, if I understand it correctly, is the entire soundtrack *grabbed* from the blueray. So basically I can only confirm [Jim Green's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32318/769), but at least now you can hear the track without Flynn's voice.