# What is the song played in the "End of Line" club on Tron Legacy?

Tags: tron-legacy

At the end of the scene when Sam is in the End of Line club, Daft Punk are asked to switch up the music and they start to play a techno-style track instead of "End of Line"... What is that track called?

I understand by looking at [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32305/where-is-this-missing-part-to-the-tron-legacy-soundtrack) post there are several songs not available from any one source and it's not on the soundtrack I have. I was hoping to find it.

Comment: AFAIK, that song is a compilation of a couple different songs, and cannot be found. I've gone through a bunch of sites trying to find it, the best I've been able to do is rip it from a youtube video as music.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Daft Punk Wikia](http://daftpunk.wikia.com/wiki/End_of_Line), the song that plays immediately after "End of Line" is **"Castor"**.

This song was not found on the [Original Soundtrack Album](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron:_Legacy_%28soundtrack%29) but can be heard on the [Special Edition Bonus Disc](http://www.thedaftclub.com/music/tron-legacy-soundtrack/).

[image]

Comment: Oh yay :D Finally. Awesome intro. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I had forgotten that I was curious about this as well. Hooray! Why wasn't this included in the soundtrack I already own? :'(

Comment: @Nomkins - Dunno. Worth downloading the full OST if you get the time.

Answer (score -2):

Derezzed - Daft Punk, I think is the one you want.

Comment: Derezzed is the song played during the fight scene in the club - but the one they play when Zeus asks them to "switch it up" isn't listed on the soundtrack

Comment: I just checked, and although `"Derezzed"` follows `"End of Line"` on the soundtrack, it's not the track I was thinking of. You can hear the track just after `3:30` in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6rba8yKCNI Thanks for posting.